# SQL Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read all the similar errors here, still can't figure out why am I getting this error

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'storage'
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `storehouse`.`storage`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `storehouse`.`storage` (
      `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `quantity` INT NULL,
      `storage_room` INT NULL,
      UNIQUE INDEX `product_id_UNIQUE` (`product_id` ASC),
      INDEX `storage_room_idx` (`storage_room` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `product_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
        REFERENCES `storehouse`.`product` (`product_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `storage_room`
        FOREIGN KEY (`storage_room`)
        REFERENCES `storehouse`.`space` (`space_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I've checked: all the keys are unique

Comment: please ensure you have unique key name assigned across indexes and foreign key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to check all foreign key and constraint names in the database.
One constraint had the same name as the key-that's how mysql workbench works

Comment: That's how MySQL works. It's database behavior, not client's.

Answer (score 0):

Try and delete all rows from your tables.
Also make product_id as PRIMARY KEY. This should work.